# Como imprimir una lista en python

Tags: python, lista

holaa!, hace poco que es estoy aprendiendo python y tengo que llenar una lista con 10000 números aleatorios (bueno, también poner algunos condicionales y todo eso) el problema es que al imprimirla no me salen los 10000 números o es que acaso estoy llenando mal la lista?
dejo aquí mi código:

```
import random

for i in range (0,10000):
    r=0 
    msjnoen=[]
    for j in range(0,1000):
        x=random.random()
        m=round(x,2)
        if m<=0.13:
            r+=1       
    msjnoen.append(r)

for f in msjnoen:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La lista `msjnoen` la necesitas crear afuera del `for` y únicamente agregar elementos con `append` adentro del `for`

En tu código lo que está pasando es que cada iteración creas una nueva lista

Así podría ser una solución:

```
import random

msjnoen = []

for i in range (0,10000):
    r = 0
    x = round(random.random(),2)
    if x <= 0.13:
        r += 1
    msjnoen.append(r)

for i in msjnoen:
    print(i)
```

**Nota:** Esto crearía una lista de 10000 elementos pero todos son 0 ó 1, como no explicaste para qué sirve la `r`, en cada iteración su valor por defecto es `0` y si `x` es menor a `0.13` entonces `r` es `1`, pero tal vez tengas que adaptar tu lógica o agregar más información a tu pregunta